# How can I give an option to user to set baseurl?

Tags: ionic4

I have built an app using ionic but my clients will be using different servers for accessing API. How can I give an option to set the base url by the user to call the desired server API?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

**The temporary way:**

This way, when the app is closed, it reset to the default api:

1. create a service `ionic generate service`
2. in this service, make a variable that will have the url you need
3. make some getter and setter
4. import this service where you need it (were you change your api, and in your api service)

**The permanent way:**

Use the [file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) to make, for example, a JSON that you will read/write with the api url in it.

Answer (score 0):

set your base url in `environment.ts` file and use in any of service

```
export  const  environment  = {
    production:  false,
    baseUrl:  'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    Userlogin(data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'user/login', data);
    }
}
```